favicons return 403 forbidden on local machine
We have recently upgraded our favicons so that they are accessed via the apache Alias function. They work just fine on several of our servers, but on my local development machine they return 403 errors.
The various servers are running Ubuntu; my local machine is a Mac. The stacks are pretty similar though. Before using the Alias function to locate the favicon file structure outside the docroot, we never had this problem.
This 403 issue on favicons is reported somewhat commonly. Unfortunately the standard solutions do not help. Here are some of the standard solutions:

use Require all granted in the apache config.
loosen permissions: we have set the perms to 777 for testing and on all the parent folders

The relevant portion of the config is as follows:
Alias /favicon /Users/jas/Websites/RepHunter/cfg/local/favicon/
Alias /favicon.ico /Users/jas/Websites/RepHunter/cfg/local/favicon/favicon.ico
<Directory "/Users/jas/Websites/RepHunter/favicon/>
        Options None
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride None
</Directory>

The console tab of Dev Tools shows the following:

Again: we get no such errors on the other servers--only on my local.
EDIT 1:
Taking the suggestion from Gordon Davisson, we moved the favicon files completely outside /Users. That still did not work. As a next step, we put the favicon files back into /favicon in the docroot, the way you are supposed to do it, without using the alias. That removed the 403 errors.
Interim conclusion:

Either we still have something incorrect in the configuration
Or macOS requires that favicon files must be in the docroot, and using an apache alias does not work. This is odd because apache aliases work fine on the Mac for other types of files, and the aliases for the favicon files work just fine on other servers.

My suspicion is that there is something in the configuration that is wrong.
Another point that I should have put in the original question: the favicon actually works as seen in the browser tab for the page. It is just that we get the 403 forbidden errors in the network tab of Dev Tools for each of the six or so files in the favicon folder.

we have set the perms to 777 for testing and on all the parent folders I'll bet you forgot one of the parent folders.  Switch users to the account that the webserver runs as, and see if you can access the icon files from a plain command shell window.

It is a weird practice. Why do you need an alias for favicons? They are just images and you can access them with relative paths in your HTML. Seems you are complicating the matters.

In recent versions of macOS, some parts of users' home directories have privacy protections that're separate from regular file permissions. I wouldn't expect a "Websites" subdirectory to be affected, but moving the directory outside of your home dir might solve it. See "What and how does macOS Mojave implement to restrict applications access to personal data?" and 'Why do I get "ls: Desktop: Operation not permitted" when I own Desktop?'

@John Gordon - I did not clearly state the perms--as a test we changed the perms on the files, the directory and all parent directories. Plus we have another directory in the same relative location outside the docroot that has no 403 problems, with normal permissions.

@Raptor - the alias is to allow a structure where for different versions of the websites, there are different files used. The Alias mechamism allows us to have symlinks so that each domain gets its own version of the file, but without having to adjust the structure in other ways. This would be an interesting point you bring up, except that none of our servers running ubuntu have any problems with 403 on the favicons--only the one on macOS. So something is different with the macOS. Since symlinks are involved, perhpas that's fine on ubuntu, but not on macOS?

@Gordon Davisson - we are using Alias directives for some directories outside the docroot for other purposes with no problems. It is only a problem for favicons.

@JeffreySimon since you mention that the issue only happens in macOS, you might want to check & remove the special attributes in the files. See this. Better so, you might want to move the files out of /Users/ folder, as system permission might forbid you from accessing the folder, since the web server is probably using another user to run.

@JeffreySimon Outside the docroot: not a problem. Inside a user's home directory: maybe a problem. I'd recommend putting it someplace else and testing whether that solves the problem.

@Raptor - the entire docroot is under /Users and all the directories outside the docroot are also under /Users. So the issue has to be something to do with the Alias mechanism.

@Gordon Daviison - might be worth a test to put it outside /Users just to see what happens.
